# How to Convert this Linq Query into Lambda Expression

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
        foreach (lc_ShoppingCart sc in shQuery)
        {
            //Decrement the Product Table's Total Remaining row with the quantity
            var ProductInventoryQuery = (from pr in db.lc_ProductInventories
                                         join c in db.lc_ColorTables on pr.Color equals c.Color
                                         join s in db.lc_SizeTables on pr.Size equals s.Size
                                         where pr.ProductID == Convert.ToInt32(sc.ProductID)
                                         where pr.Color == c.Color
                                         where pr.Size == s.Size
                                         select pr).First();
            ProductInventoryQuery.Quantity = ProductInventoryQuery.Quantity - sc.Quantity;
        }
```

Comment: use LinqPad  http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
var ProductInventoryQuery = 
       db.lc_ProductInventories.Where(w => w.ProductID == Convert.ToInt32(sc.ProductID))
         .Join(db.lc_ColorTables, p => p.Color, ct => ct.Color, (p, ct) => new { ProdInv = p, ColorTables = ct })
         .Join(db.lc_SizeTables, p => p.Size, st => st.Color, (p, st) => new { ProdInv = p, SizeTables = st })
         .First();
```